# SQLSTATE[08006] [7] FATAL: the database system is in recovery mode

Tags: postgresql, php, postgis

I have some problem with PostgreSQL and PostGIS.

I received an error after running the below query with some coordinates on special raster file.

It worked fine until last week.

The query is:

```
select (ST_ValueCount(ST_Union(ST_Clip(r.rast,r.geom,true),1,'area_sum'))).* from (select * ,(SELECT (ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('{ "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[47.48034200000001,39.13347600000003],[47.49611600000003,39.114525000000015],[47.510418000000016,39.10534899999999],[47.52599799999996,39.08644900000013],[47.54254200000014,39.05803700000013],[47.53256200000004,39.0290940000001],[47.52131200000002,39.00986000000012],[47.49699400000003,38.99015700000001],[47.498607000000106,38.97137000000009],[47.52537600000005,38.96289400000006],[47.52689400000003,38.94405700000004],[47.54134800000014,38.92563300000012],[47.529907000000094,38.906041000000016],[47.519521,38.87627100000009],[47.521041000000025,38.85683000000006],[47.54817600000001,38.83865400000002],[47.58924400000001,38.80162500000006],[47.59110200000009,38.762773000000095],......]]}'), 4326)))as geom from public.layer where filename in ( 'myrasterfile.tif') ) as r where ST_Intersects(r.rast,r.geom))
```

The error is:

> ```
> SQLSTATE[08006] [7] FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
> ```

Why does my PostgreSQL instance go into recovery mode on this query process?

What should I do?

Comment: `the database system is in recovery mode` - this error is possible at the time of connecting to the database. It is not possible to send any queries yet. Look in the database logs for the real reason for switching to recovery mode, it will be somewhere before that.

Comment: Your database crashed, most likely because it ran out of memory. Look at the log file for details and adjust your configuration. Disable memory overcommit on the operating system.

Answer (score 2):

##### My case: RDS PostgreSql DB status was `Storage-full`

So I couldn't connect to it from my client w/ the fatal error in the original post.

##### Solution:

1. connect to the [AWS web console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/rds/home): **RDS** > **Databases** > **db-name**
2. **Modify** > **Allocated storage** >> increase the storage size
3. (optional) *Enable storage autoscaling*
4. Continue (preview changes) >> Save

Extra: you may want to check why the storage has exceeded, maybe safely delete some unwanted rows and review the storage size again according to your needs vs budget.